# Download file based on date modified from SFTP

Tags: c#, sftp, sharpssh

Is there a way to get the files from SFTP server that should be based on modified date using Tamir.SharpSsh? Currently I am downloading files by file name but my requirement is by Date Modified.

```
var sftp = new Sftp(Host, UserName, Password);
sftp.Connect();
sftp.Get(sourcePath+"/*.*." + name + "*", destinationPath);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SharpSsh does not allow that. It's a dead project, do not use it.

Anyway, I took a look at the code to assess how difficult it would be add possibility to retrieve file timestamp using the `Sftp.GetFileList` (since the library is open source).

You would have to:

- Add a timestamp field to the `ChannelSftp.LsEntry`
- Add parsing out timestamp from the `SSH_FXP_NAME` packet to the `ChannelSftp.ls` method
- Modify (or add an alternative to) the `Sftp.GetFileList` to return not only file name, but also the timestamp (and other file metadata).

---

Alternatively, you can use [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library). You can use its [`Session.GetFiles` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles) with a [file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask). E.g. a [file mask `*>7D` selects all files modified in the last week](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

SFTP protocol doesn't let you specify the filemask for the operation. Processing of the mask you pass is done on the client side anyway. So you can only list all files, then traverse the list and pick the files you need by certain criteria.

Comment: Problem with SharpSSh is that it does not allow you to retrieve any file attribute.