# How to distinguish a directory in SFTP listing retrieved using SharpSSH?

Tags: c#, sftp, sharpssh

I need to recursively download files from the server to SFTP by SharpSsh. But I do not understand how to determine that the file name or the directory.
Now I do so

```
 static void recDir(string remotePath, string localPath)
 {
     Sftp _c = this.sftp;
     ArrayList FileList = _c.GetFileList(remotePath);
     FileList.Remove(".");
     FileList.Remove("..");
     for (int i = 0; i < FileList.Count; i++)
     {
         try
         {
             _c.Get(remotePath + "/" + FileList[i], localPath + "/" + FileList[i]);

             Console.WriteLine("File: " + remotePath + "/" + FileList[i]);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Dir: " + remotePath + "/" + FileList[i]);
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath + "/" + FileList[i]);
                recDir(remotePath + "/" + FileList[i], localPath + "/" + FileList[i]);
         }
     }
 }
```

It works, but it seems not correct.

Comment: your code seems like when any exception occurred then you tried to recursion not clear where you want recursion..

Comment: No idea what this means:  `It works, but it seems not correct.`

Comment: @Dan-o I'm quite sure it means that the OP is trying to make robust code, not code that "just happen to work". Using exceptions for regular program flow is smelly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharpSSH API does not allow that. But you can code it as SharpSSH is open source. Note that SharpSSH is a poor choice though. It's not maintained for years.

---

See my answers to another similar SharpSSH questions:

- [Download file based on date modified from SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25543826/850848).
- [Get file size from SFTP using SharpSSH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26023293/850848).

Or use another SFTP library:

- [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) has the method `SftpClient.ListDirectory` returning the `IEnumerable<SftpFile>`. The `SftpFile` has the `.IsDirectory` property
- [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) has the method [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) returning (via the `RemoteDirectoryInfo.Files`) a collection of the [`RemoteFileInfo`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotefileinfo) with property `.IsDirectory`
  *(I'm the author of WinSCP .NET assembly)*